# Found com1 folder inside Pictures un Windows 10

Tags: windows, photos, recovery

So the problem is as it follows.

Recentley I tried to restore Windows un various options. The thing is everytime I tried this It kept hanging and, at some point it would ask me to select another options.

Today I went into Pictures and I found mostly all files had dissapeared. By using some recovery software I found a Thumb.ms folder, which has inside a com1 folder with another folder that I can't access to and name with strange characters, which seems to have my photos.

How can I enter in the folder? As I'm not willing to pay for a license of the software in order to recover the files.

Thanks! And sorry if my english is a little bad.

Answer (score 0):

get a cmd prompt at the pictures folder:

```
ren com*.* abc*.*
```